# Is it possible to query multiple records from the same most recent date

Tags: sql

I have a query that returns the following results

```
Date        Type          
6/7/18      R104            
6/7/18      Sunset         
6/7/18      Rabbit-T          
6/7/18      Sunset         
6/8/18      R104            
6/8/18      S400           
6/9/18      Singer        
6/9/18      Sunset          
6/9/18      Rabbit-M      
6/9/18      Sunset         
6/9/18      Sunset
```

Is it possible to only pull the records from the most recent date (here 6/9/18) regardless of what the record is?

This is my query

```
 SELECT   
 ot.sale_date AS "Sale Date"  
 , otr.type_33 AS "Type"  
 , ide.s_style AS "Style"  
 , att.att_color AS "Color"  



FROM 
SYSTEM.order_tracking as ot
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSTEM.order_type as otr
on ot.clientID=otr.clientID and ot.salesperiod=otr.salesperiod and 
ot.CUSTHBDT_UID=otr.CUSTHBDT_UID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSTEM.item_descriptions_East as ide 
on otr.clientID=ide.clientID and otr.salesperiod=ide.salesperiod and 
otr.CUSTHBDU_UID=ide.CUSTHBDU_UID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSTEM.attributes as att 
on ide.clientID=att.clientID and ide.salesperiod=att.salesperiod and 
 ide.CUSTHBDV_UID=att.CUSTHBDV_UID



WHERE
ot.access_code = '1'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Include the query you are using is also nice.

Comment: `ORDER BY "Date" DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES`

Comment: tried that. My program isn't liking FETCH or first 1 row

Answer (score 3):

You could use a subquery to filter on latest date records available in the table

```
select *
from table
where date = (select max(date) from table)
```

Remember to have an index on `table(date)` to speed up retrieval.

---

This should work for most DBMS even those ones which don't support:

- analytical functions like `rank()`
- `TOP n WITH TIES`

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports `RANK`, then you may try this:

```
SELECT Date, Type
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) rank
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rank = 1;
```

This option gives you some flexibility in the case you need to break ties.  In that case, you could simply add another level of sorting to the `ORDER BY` clause used with `RANK`.

Comment: I added my query. How would that fit into there?

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using

```
WHERE   
having date=max(date)
```

That did the trick

Comment: You should mark one the other answers correct and not post your own answer.

Comment: Does my proposed solution not work? Using HAVING for comparison without group by and for non aggregation is a tricky way and one should understand what it brings.

Comment: Sorry, it did not. It was asking for an identifier when I tried to submit it